# Oracle custom program is generating blank output report

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oraclereports

[image]

We have created one custom report which will generate the xml output. But somehow from last few days, it's returning blank output. No data in output report.

When we run the query behind the report, it's returning data. Any suggestions on how to debug?

Comment: What changed during the last few days?

Comment: Nothing is changed. I have checked for special characters in data also. No luck so far

Comment: If the output has changed, other than data values, then something has changed. You just have not found it yet. You know it is not the query, so how is the result set sent back to the client? Do you have procedures which silently squash exceptions, how are parameters sent to the server? Has a table changed and is there a select * on that table? ... You need to just trace back through each step in the process.

Comment: We recently upgraded DB from 12c to 19c and the issue started from then on. No code change no config changes made on the report.